# Java - Calling a variable from a different class which's value is taken from a JTextField when a JButton has been pressed

Tags: java, swing, variables, awt, event-listener

Im trying to create a choose your own destiny adventure game. I have created the gui which looks like this:

[image]

The JTextField shown is going to be the input box which is entered when the button is pressed. Im trying to write the code so that when the button is pressed, its contents is saved to a variable called UserInput, which i can then call up in the main class to use its contents.

My main class is currently just:

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int t = 0;
        int st = 0;
        int h = 0;

        Texts textObject = new Texts();
        textObject.TextList();

        Commands commandObject = new Commands();
        commandObject.commands();

        GUImain guiObject = new GUImain();
        guiObject.displayGUI();

        String User_Input = guiObject.();       
    }
}
```

The last line is where i want to call up the String from the GUImain class

This is my GUImain class I've tried to cut out any irrelivent code for this question:

```
import's (lots of them);

public class GUImain 
{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;
    private ImageIcon image1;

    public void displayGUI() 
    {
        this.frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    //Launch the application.
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GUImain window = new GUImain();
    }


    //Create the application.
    public GUImain() 
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 611, 471);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
```

...

Creating the JButton and my attempt at making it link to the Text field and save its contents to the variable UserInput, which i want to call up from the main class:

```
        JButton btnEnter = new JButton("Enter"); //enter button
        btnOptions.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public String UserInput = "null";
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
               UserInput = textField.getText();
            }
            public String getUserInput()
            {
               return UserInput;
            }
        });
        btnEnter.setBounds(518, 404, 85, 39);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnEnter);
```

...

Creating the Text Field:

```
        textField = new JTextField(""); 
        textField.setBounds(5, 410, 508, 28);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);
```

I'm just starting to learn java so sorry for asking such a basic question, but I've been stuck on it for quite a while now.

Thanks for your time and help.

Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try using 'GUImain' as the inner class in class 'Main' and declare a variable

```
public String UserInput = "null";
```

in 'Main' class. This variable can now be used in both your classes.

Comment: sorry to ask for baby steps but I'm not sure how to implement that can you show me?

Comment: class A {
int a;   
   class B {
      int b;
   }
}

// class B can access vars. of class A
but class A can't access vars. in class B directly (instead it has to instantiate class B).

i would rather recommend you to learn about it on tutorialspoint or similar site and read some good books to get a hold on basics.

Head First JAVA is awesome book to start with